# Smarty: PHP file_get_contents not finding file

Tags: php, macos, smarty, osx-elcapitan

I’ve just bought a new MacBook and have made a new local development set up, and have been through **PHP installation**, set up for user rather than root and tested and all seems to work okay. My project is running on **Smarty**, which also seems to work okay.

However file_get_contents script contained in my project is returning a `"failed to open stream: No such file or directory"` error message. However, my file is in the right place and this script was working on my previous computer (OSX 10.11). I’ve just copied files over from the old computer rather than doing a full migration, so I’m wondering if it’s anything to do with file permissions or something rather than something wrong with my PHP installation.

Has anyone come across something similar – I’ve been wracking my brains trying to even formulate this query.

Comment: Does the web server have read access to the file in question?

Comment: this is all Localhost, and I tried max permissions for all files.

Comment: Please try to run `file_exists()` to verify, that the file really exists in that place. I bet you are working with a wrong path. ;-)